# Android MotionLayout show RecyclerView Animation Direction is wrong

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to show `RecyclerView` with `MotionLayout`.
My problem is that the animation is showing from **left upper corner** to **bottom right corner**.**(You can see the gif below)** What I need is to be shown from **top to bottom**.
Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

Below is my `Activity` XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/action_bar_neu_scene">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_tool_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/main_bg"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_message_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_user_name_TV"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_user_name_TV"
        app:tint="@color/awsdk_color_blackcurrant_60" />


    <org.meuhedet.android.ui.general.controls.AppTextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_user_name_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actionMenuView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_rv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/main_bg"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_neu_tool_bar_container"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:spanCount="3"
    tools:itemCount="5"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_action_bar" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is my `MotionScene XML`:

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="2600">
    <KeyFrameSet>

    </KeyFrameSet>

    <OnSwipe
        motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
        motion:touchAnchorId="action_bar_neu_users_rv"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />


</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:translationZ="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_neu_tool_bar_container" />

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="1.0"
        android:translationZ="1dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_neu_tool_bar_container" />
</ConstraintSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the answer for this issue.
The problem was that I'm setting the `visibility` to `View.GONE`
The right way is to use `KeyAttribute` within `KeyFrameSet` and on `framePosition` 98+/- set the `Visibility` to `Invisible`. See the example below. Hope this will save a lot of time to others.

[image]

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="2600">
    <KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:framePosition="1"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/action_bar_neu_users_rv" />

        <KeyAttribute
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:framePosition="98"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/action_bar_neu_users_rv" />
    </KeyFrameSet>


</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_neu_users_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:alpha="1.0"
        android:visibility="visible"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</ConstraintSet>
```